# Getting connection string from dll which contains Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to fix an app that references a .dll which contains Entity Framework code (.edmx, etc...).  I do not have the source so I cannot determine the connection string the edmx file uses.  When I run the app I get exceptions that the data source cannot be reached.  I have the correct .mdf file that EF is "supposed" to be using, but since I cannot see the connection string, I can't verify this.

Is there another way(tool) to figure out what the connection string is for this dll?

Comment: Do you have a separate app.config per chance? The connection string is typically defined in app.config of the CALLING assembly, because of reasons that are at this point only too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite weird that this 3rd part dll doesn't use a configuration key to get the connection string: entity framework creates a key every time you add a connection. 
If the connection is hard-coded you need to use a tool like Reflector to get the connection string

http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1

Comment: use the .net reflector then. you will be able to get the connection string....finger crossed they haven't user .NET Obfuscator

Answer (score 0):

You can access the following property:

```
var connStr = Context.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

This will show you the connection string being used, minus any credentials. The `Connection` property differs slightly depending upon the version of EF you're using. In EFCF it's:

```
var connStr = Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```